# I'd like to compare these two sentences - "do a job of"

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. I'm currently doing a job of designing a website.

I think this implies more professionnality by using a word 'job'. this sentence would never imply that I'm at the moment designing a website sitting on a chair and using computer. Rather, It would imply that designing a website is what I spend most of my time at these days.

> 2. I'm currently designing a website.

this could imply that I'm currently in front of computer designing a website.

So, when I describe what I usually do these days, I would say #1. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, no. You'd use #2, and if you think that implies what you are doing right this moment (which it wouldn't if you were asked 'What are you doing these days?'), you could quite easily change it to "I currently design websites" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm currently designing a website" does imply ongoing action, but not necessarily that you are doing it right this second. Partly this is because the reader/listener knows what you are doing right this second; you are writing/speaking that sentence.

It also has the backing of a lot of similarly constructed idioms. For instance "I'm currently writing a novel" is often understood to mean that the speaker has an idea for a novel, and maybe a chapter or two or an outline, but probably hasn't actually written anything for weeks, months or years. This goes back to an old stereotype of a kind of intellectual that thinks he's better than he is, that "is currently writing a novel" and has been for twenty or thirty years.